# Asking questions in the same subject repeatedly but without flooding

Tags: discussion

I'm reading a book in basic algebraic geometry and sometimes I don't know some details of the proofs and examples the author gives. I'm a really beginner in commutative algebra and algebraic geometry and I'm trying to understand this subject by myself in my summer vacations.

So, I'm using this site to follow this book which it helped me a lot.

In this week, I'm studying the chapter which explains the concept of dimension of a variety, hence I've been asked four questions with the same subject (dimension):

[Why $k(\mathbb A^n)=k(T_1,\ldots,T_n)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613786/why-k-mathbb-an-kt-1-ldots-t-n)

[Help in this easy lemma about dimension in algebraic geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614036/help-in-this-easy-lemma-about-dimension-in-algebraic-geometry)

[If $X=\{x\}$, then $\dim(X)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614919/if-x-x-then-dimx-0)

[Dimension of a curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615027/dimension-of-a-curve)

I didn't asked these questions in the same day to make sure I'm not  flooding the site and I tried to give the context of every question and make clear what are my doubts and what I know of the subject.

I follow the meta site daily, I know the rules of the main site and I don't think I broke any of them. However, my last question was downvoted and one user said me it happened maybe because I'm asking many questions with the same subject repeatedly.

I'm not asking *why* this question was downvoted, I know it's a subjective matter, but I believe that a downvote has a function to help us to meet the quality standards of the MSE site.

So, I would like to know if what I'm doing is under the quality standards of the MSE site, Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks a lot

Comment: (Re: one user said me it happened maybe because I'm asking many questions with the same subject repeatedly) no, that's not exactly what the user [is saying](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615027/dimension-of-a-curve#comment1295875_615027)

Comment: @GrigoryM Ok, that's not exactly what he said, anyway his comment make me think about this.

Comment: If no user said so, please do not state that one user said so, even if what some user did say made you think about whatever it made you think about.

Comment: Well, since the OP didn't use quotation marks, I think the way he rephrased it is quite valid.

Comment: @dreamer Let us wait for you to discover that somebody "rephrased" some of your words to make them say something quite different and we will see if your opinion stays the same.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's a built-in hard limit on the number of the questions you can ask. As long as the questions you are asking are good, I see no reason why you should refrain from asking as many as you are allowed.

I think the people who downvoted your question acted wrongly. It is true you are asking many questions that turn on relatively basic algebraic facts, and that you might want to review basic graduate level algebra before proceeding with learning algebraic geometry. However, it seems like your questions reflect honest effort and perplexity, and downvoting people who are having trouble learning certain concepts seems unproductive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @user75086 If it is helpful then you can accept it.

Comment: "it seems like your questions reflect honest effort and perplexity, and downvoting people who are having trouble learning certain concepts seems unproductive" insta-+1